VS code with C# Dev Kit on Linux Mint : .NET location: Not found
I have installed the .NET SDK, then VS Code, then the C# Dev kit on VS code.
Whern I try to create a new project (ctrl + shift + P -> .NET: New Project), I get a popup that says
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer client: couldn't create connection to server.

The error in output looks like
Dotnet path: /usr/bin/dotnet
Activating C# + C# Dev Kit...
waiting for named pipe information from server...
[stderr] You must install .NET to run this application.

App: /home/eric/.vscode/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-2.33.17-linux-x64/.roslyn/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.LanguageServer
Architecture: x64
App host version: 8.0.2
.NET location: Not found

I have verified that dotnet is, in fact, available at /usr/bin/dotnet
I can run dotnet --version just fine
VS Code is installed locally, it is not sandboxed in a flatpack.
